# Is a contract between two third parties actionable?

Tags: contract-law

Kickstart claims "Kickstarter's Terms of Use require creators to fulfill all rewards of their project or refund any backer whose reward they do not or cannot fulfill."[1](https://www.kickstarter.com/blog/accountability-on-kickstarter)

And it goes further threatening the creator with lawsuit from backers:
[image: If your project is successfully funded, you are required to fulfill all rewards or refund any backer whose reward you do not or can not fulfill. A failure to do so could result in damage to your reputation or even legal action on behalf of your backers.]

But since "Kickstarter's Terms of Use" is a contract between Kickstarter and a creator, how a backer can sue a creator who fails to deliver a promised functionality for a product?

Comment: Note that the tickbox underneath all that says "I have read these *_Important Reminders_*, the Terms of Use...." - the "Your Responsibility" part is an *_important reminder_* that you have a potential legal obligation to your backers - remember, in the US, _anyone can sue anyone_.

Comment: But is a Kickstarter Campaing a contract?

Comment: It doesnt matter, remember the "in the US, anyone can sue anyone" part of my comment.  You received financial backing, and it could definitely be argued in court that you have a fiduciary duty to them and cannot just take the money and run.  But even if that argument fails, it will have failed *in court*, meaning the legal action will have been taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Because the contract is between the creator and the backer

> Kickstarter is not a part of this contract — the contract is a direct legal agreement between creators and their backers. Here are the terms that govern that agreement:

Kickstarter has separate agreements with creators and backers but the creators and backers have their own contract.

Comment: Do we know that this isn't an English contract? No possibility of CRPTA 1999? https://law.stackexchange.com/a/48957

Answer (score 0):

> how a backer can sue a creator who fails to deliver a promised functionality for a product?

"*Legal action on behalf of your backers*" means that Kickstarter (not the backers) will sue the creator. It will do that after the backers complain — to honor its contract with them and/or as a goodwill gesture.

Comment: Silent downvote is pretty much like silent fart.