# What is my relationship with a service company contracted by my insurance company?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, legal-terms

I am wondering about the legal terminologies that define a relationship that I have with a service company. Some maintenance work was needed for several appliances at my home, so I contacted my warranty company. My home warranty company dispatched a technician from a service company to take care of it. I paid my warranty company a service fee, which I think of as a deductible in an insurance policy.

Since I didn't pay the service company directly, legally am I still a client of the service company? I was told by them that I do not have a client relationship with them as the warranty company was the client in this transaction. Is that correct? I am curious what legal terms/concepts are applicable in this situation and if I have a legal relationship with a service company which provides service on properties I own but is not paid by me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### None

The contractual chain is you *<->* warranty company *<->* (potentially others you don’t know about) *<->* service provider.

Should something go wrong, you would sue your warranty company who might (it is up to them) then sue the service provider. Notwithstanding, it’s likely the service company owes you a duty of care and would be directly liable to you for a negligence claim.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this answer before the OP added the U.S. tag. Thus this answer doesn't apply any more.

I'll dilate on Dale M's [comment](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/44816/what-is-my-relationship-with-a-service-company-contracted-by-my-insurance-compan#comment84605_44817) that's alluding to the [Contracts (Rights of Third Parties) Act 1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contracts_(Rights_of_Third_Parties)_Act_1999). I'll quote England textbooks that present it better than I can.

[Richard](https://www.uclan.ac.uk/staff_profiles/richard-taylor.php) and [Damian](https://www.slaughterandmay.com/who-we-are/partners/damian-taylor/) Taylor. [*Contract Law Directions* (2019 7 ed)](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/contract-law-directions-9780198836599?&lang=en&).  p 82.

> [image]

Poole, Shaw-Mellors. [*Contract Law Concentrate* (4 ed 2019)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Contract-Law-Concentrate-Jill-Pool/dp/0198840446/ref=dp_ob_title_bk). p 82.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, added the "United States" tag.

Answer (score -1):

> What is my relationship with a service company contracted by my insurance company?

You are the *obligee* or *beneficiary*, where as the service company is the *obligor*.

You have a contract only with the warranty company (to which you interchangeably refer as *insurance company*), whereas the service company has a contract only with the warranty company. Those are the legal relationships that exist in the scenario you outline.

That being said, a beneficiary may take legal action against the obligor if something goes wrong, regardless of the fact that the obligor entered its contract with an entity other than the beneficiary.

Comment: What makes the service company an obligor to the end user? They are hired to perform some action by the warranty company. I have not heard of this relationship before and am curious.

Comment: Third parties, even if they benefit, generally have no right to sue under contract (suits under tort or equity are ok). This is the doctrine of privity. The UK has passed legislation to allow this but AFAIK they are unique in this in common law jurisdictions.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite "*What makes the service company an obligor to the end user?*" The contract intent that the performance for which the service company was hired be *in favor of* the end user. See entry for *obligee* in Black's Law Dict. See also [Restatement (Second) of Contracts](https://www.nylitigationfirm.com/files/restat.pdf) at § 302 and § 309(1) (regarding the *duty to a beneficiary*). Note that *Id.* at § 309(4) speaks in terms of the *beneficiary's rights against the promisor* notwithsanding that the contract is between the promisor and the promisee. Similarly, *Id.* at § 311(4) & 328(2).

Comment: @DaleM "*Third parties, even if they benefit, generally have no right to sue under contract*". Wrong. You might have in mind law that is --at best-- obsolete and superseded, or where the intent was not expressly the benefit of a third-party. See [*Smith v. Town of Cramerton* (U.S. Dist. Court, W.D. North Carolina. 2019)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/infdco20190906984) (recognizing the right of a third-party beneficiary to sue for breach of contract, citing cases). Also [*WM. T. Burnett Holdings v. Berg Bros.*, 175 A.3d 876, 880-881 (2017)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/inmdco20171221351).

Comment: Even if the contract were in North Carolina, how is the OP “a direct and not incidental beneficiary”?

Comment: @DaleM I don't have OP's policy in hand, but it is common practice that insurance companies enter contracts [with providers] clearly intended for the benefit of insurer's customers. There is nothing incidental about that. Also, N.C. is not the only jurisdiction recognizing the beneficiary's right to enforce a contract. The other link is from Maryland, and it reflects that courts since 1948 or earlier have been "gradually" recognizing this right.

Comment: So if the service provider doesn't manage to fix my washing machine, I go to the warranty provider. If the service provider causes huge water damage through negligence while trying to fix my washing machine, I sue the service provider, or still the warranty provider?

Comment: @gnasher729 "*if the service provider doesn't manage to fix my washing machine, I go to the warranty provider*".Let's pause there. Subject to the contract between end user & warranty co. and/or the one between service co. & warranty co. providing otherwise, the *Restatement* and cited cases reflect that the end user may proceed against either company to enforce that of which he is beneficiary. The same applies in the event of *huge water damage through negligence* because an evidently basic assumption in both contracts is that the supplier will not make things worse as a result of performance.

Comment: This makes sense to me since the end user is very clearly an intended 3rd party beneficiary of the agreement between the insurance company and the service company.

Comment: The Restatement (Second) of Contracts is available [here](https://www.fbcoverup.com/docs/library/1981-Restatement-Second-of-Contracts-1981.pdf), now that the law firm from the link above (in one of my previous comments) removed that resource and posted some useless "overview of contract law" instead.